# Build docker image from local instead of git clone

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, docker

I've been stuck on this for a while now, and would like the best-practice approach to this issue.

I have built an app in Go that I would like to publish on AWS with Docker. I was following the [AWS instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/go_docker_platform.html) on how to set it up, however when I try the build command, I get the following error:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 182.8 MB
Step 1/1 : FROM golang:1.8.1-onbuild
# Executing 3 build triggers...
Step 1/1 : COPY . /go/src/app
Step 1/1 : RUN go-wrapper download
 ---> Running in e6bc4dd7dc44
+ exec go get -v -d
github.com/<myaccount>/<myapp> (download)
# cd .; git clone https://github.com/<myaccount>/<myapp> 
/go/src/github.com/<myaccount>/<myapp>
Cloning into '/go/src/github.com/<myaccount>/<myapp>'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
```

I've googled a bit, and it appears this could be caused by the fact that the repo is set to private, which I'd like to keep that way. A common approach appears to be embedding credentials or ssh keys within the image for deployment, which sounds to go against any recommendation in terms of security (or even common sense).

Is there any way I can still do this? Why is it even trying to clone anything in the first place, the code is already there?

**EDIT**

The Dockerfile only contains the following line

```
FROM golang:1.8.1-onbuild
```

Comment: If you copy the source into the GOPATH, it won't need to clone the repo. How are you building this exactly?

Comment: Please include your Dockerfile.

Comment: Why are you running the `go-wrapper download` when you already have the files there?

Comment: I have added the content of the Dockerfile. There's not much in there, so I don't know why it won't just fetch it from the GOPATH, or is running the go-wrapper download. As you can tell, my Docker knowledge is pretty thin, it practically worked out of the box last time I used it (4 months ago).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The download is part of the `onbuild` in the image you are using. You can see [their dockerfile here](https://github.com/docker-library/golang/blob/132cd70768e3bc269902e4c7b579203f66dc9f64/1.8/onbuild/Dockerfile). If you don't want that step included, switch over to `FROM golang:1.8.1` and do the copy and install steps in your Dockerfile. e.g.

```
FROM golang:1.8.1

RUN mkdir -p /go/src/app
WORKDIR /go/src/app

CMD ["go-wrapper", "run"]

COPY . /go/src/app
RUN go-wrapper install
```